# HTTP redirect to HTTPS AWS EC2 with Load Balancer

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here's my set up:

EC2 with Apache using elastic load balancer.

I'm looking to have all http traffic redirect automatically to https. I found this reco and tried it by adding to my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

However, this didn't work before or after I restarted the server. HTTP didn't redirect and my sites threw all sorts of errors until I removed the rule from my config.

I'm thinking that I'm updating the file wrong or have the load balancer set up incorrectly. For the listeners for the load balancer I have LB protocol HTTP with port 80 with instance protocol HTTP and instance port 80. I have LB protocol HTTPS on port 443 with instance port 443. My SSL is on this latter protocol.

Any idea where to head from here?

Comment: Please include the errors. Also include the relevant apache conf that shows how your site is configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration that you have mentioned should work well. The problem might be that the `mod_rewrite` module is not loaded. Add below lines to your apache configuration to load rewrite module.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

You can try below configuration which is much simpler than what you are using.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the problem. Worked perfectly after loading the `mod_rewrite` module. This is a totally new area for me. Do I need to "close" that module or similar? I put all of your above code at the end of my httpd file. Wondering if I need to add anything at the end of your code in case I ever need to add something else at the end of the httpd file.

Comment: If you are applying this redirect rule for a particular `VirtualHost` then place these rules inside them. If you want redirection to happen for all `VirtualHost`s then putting them at the beginning or end doesn't matter.

Comment: For future questions to apache or other services please post in serverfault.com as stackoverflow.com is dedicated for programming questions.

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, `%{HTTPS} off` only works if the instance is receiving traffic on port 443 or over SSL.  In the other hand, `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` works when the SSL stops at the load balancer and all traffic is redirected to the instance on port 80.